# IE6 Covering Div

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I have a Google Map on one web page where I want to disable both scrolling and zooming. I accomplish this by having an empty DIV element with absolute positioning cover the map area.

Firefox/Chrome work fine, but IE6 doesn't really care about this DIV. For some reason, it just lets me drag the map. I set the DIVs background color to green, and verified that the DIV was indeed being displayed. Weird thing is, when the DIV has a visible color, it works. It blocks all events from being transferred to the map. But when the color is transparent, it doesn't work.

Any ideas why IE6 does so? I've googled a lot and all I come up with are z-index bugs, which this probably is not, since the DIV works fine with a solid background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in IE6/7, try using a fully transparent background image, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a background-color and `visibility: hidden;`

If that doesn't work, try one of the hasLayout tricks on this page: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout